# Ruby output formats differently on dynamic v. static input

Tags: ruby, string, io

FYI: Fist time I've written Ruby.

We have to write an Address Book program.  I have many parts working at this point but have run into something I don't get.

I add contacts to the address book statically before the program runs.  Then I try to have a user add a contact dynamically.  When I print this address book the contacts added statically are printed according to formatting I expect, but the ones added dynamically are all over the place.

I've added all my code here.  It's sort of a big chunk but not too bad...

```
# Address class
class Address
attr_accessor :street, :city, :state, :zip

# default constructor
def initialize(*args)
  if (args.size == 0 )
    @street = @city = @state = @zip = ""
  elsif (args.size == 4)
    @street = args[0]
    @city = args[1]
    @state = args[2]
    @zip = args[3]
  else
    puts('Constructor takes 0 or 4 arguments.  No address information has been set.')
  end

end

# string representation of address
def to_s
    "    " + @street + "\n" + \
    "    " + @city + " " + @state  + ", " + @zip
end
end


# Person class which holds full name, phone, and 
# address as an object
class Person
attr_accessor :fname, :lname, :phone, :address
def initialize(*args)
  if (args.size == 0 )
    @fname = @lname = @phone = ""
    @address = Address.new
  elsif (args.size == 4)
    @fname = args[0]
    @lname = args[1]
    @phone = args[2]
    @address = args[3]
  else
    puts('Incorrect number of arguments.')
  end

end
# returns full name    
def full_name
    @lname + ", " + @fname
end

def to_s
    "    " + full_name + "\n" + \
    @address.to_s  + "\n" + \
    "    " + @phone
end
end

# AddressBook class to hold addresses
class AddressBook
def initialize
    # empty array
    @persons = []
end

# adds a person to the address book
def add(person)

    @persons += [person]
    @persons = @persons.sort{|a,b| by_name(a,b)}
end

def by_name(a,b)
    if  a.lname  == b.lname
        a.fname  <=> b.fname
    else
        a.lname <=> b.lname
    end
end


# removes a person from the address book
def remove(person)
    # Use Array#delete
    @persons.delete(person)
end

def to_s
  add_book = ""
  for p in @persons do
    add_book += p.to_s + "\n\n"
  end
  return add_book
end
end

#
# Here I add three contacts in two different ways
#

#
# FIRST ONE
#
sandy_addr = Address.new
sandy_addr.street = "324 Campus Dr."
sandy_addr.city   = "College Park"
sandy_addr.state  = "OH"
sandy_addr.zip    = "55555"

sandy = Person.new
sandy.fname = "Sandy"
sandy.lname  = "Koh"
sandy.phone = "651-442-5710"
sandy.address = sandy_addr

#
# SECOND ONE
#
bill_addr = Address.new('536 Green Rd.', "Saint Paul", "MN", "56545")
bill = Person.new('William', 'Perry', '675-778-6754', bill_addr)
#
# THIRD ONE
#
angela_addr = Address.new('3390 Crookston Rd.', "Miami", "FL", "78654")
angela = Person.new('Angela', 'Anderson', '345-748-1754', angela_addr)

# Contacts added to the Address Book
@addressBook = AddressBook.new
@addressBook.add(sandy)
@addressBook.add(angela)
@addressBook.add(bill)


# Main method loop that runs the program
# Allows you to enter a contact, print a list of
# contacts and exit the program
def loop(addBook)
selection = 0
until(selection == 5) 
puts("Wlecome to the Address Book\n")
puts("1. Add a Contact\n")
puts("2. Delete a Contact\n")
puts("3. Retrieve a Contact\n")
puts("4. Print all Contacts\n")
puts("5. Exit Address Book\n")
selection = gets().to_i

if(selection == 1)
  addContact(addBook)
elsif(selection == 2)
  #delete_contact
elsif(selection == 3)
  #retrieve_contact
elsif(selection == 4)
  puts(addBook) 
end
end   
end

def addContact(addBook)
print("Enter First Name:  ")
fname = gets()
print("Enter Last Name:  ")
lname = gets()
print("Enter Phone Number:  ")
phone = gets()
print("Enter Street Address:  ")
street = gets()
print("Enter City:  ")
city = gets()  
print("Enter State:  ")
state = gets()
print("Enter Zip Code  ")
zip = gets()1

newAddress = Address.new(street, city, state, zip)
newPerson = Person.new(fname, lname, phone, newAddress)
addBook.add(newPerson)
out = %q/#{fname} #{lname} has been added to the Address Book./
puts(out) 
end

loop(@addressBook)
```

Comment: seeing the code is helpful, but seeing some good and bad output would be better (hint hint:) You've also got a typo on `zip = gets()1`

Comment: Thanks guys, chomp worked.  I also tried strip after the gets() and that also worked

Answer (score 2):

The [`gets`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-gets) method includes the newline so your `fname` in `addContact` will be, for example, `"Bob\n"` rather than the `"Bob"` that you're expecting. Have a look at [`chomp`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-chomp).

Comment: Thank you, I actually just found [strip](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-rstrip), and it fixed it

Answer (score 1):

You problem is probably caused because `gets()` returns the entire line including the newline character at the end.  Try replacing every `gets()` with `gets.chomp`.